# Django Rest Framework: SerializerMethodField and get_queryset

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

In my database I have two tables - `users` and `user_properties`

I need to filter output using GET parameter `phone`. But both this tables has column `phone` and has different values.

**When I doing GET request (ex. "?phone=123456789") I need to search User by phone number using not only user_properties.phone, but user.phone too!**

I googled and found a way partially to do this using get_queryset(filtering) and SerializerMethodField(to modify output):

## models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=35, max_digits=40)
    fio = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user'


class UserProperties(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_properties'
```

## views.py

```
class UserPropertiesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = UserProperties.objects.all()
serializer_class = serializers.UserPropertiesSerializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset
    # phone number from GET
    phone = self.request.query_params.get('phone')

    # Search users matches in user_properties using by phone number
    if phone:
        queryset = UserProperties.objects.all()
        users = queryset.filter(phone__contains=phone)
        return users
    else:
        return queryset
```

## serializers.py

```
class UserPropertiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
all_phones = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = models.UserProperties
    fields = ['user_id', 'phone', 'fio', 'url', 'all_phones',]

# phone numbers from user and user_properties tables
def get_all_phones(self, obj):
    # search phones in <user> table by user_id
    user_phones = models.User.objects.filter(id__exact=obj.user_id).values_list('phone', flat=True)
    # add phones from user_properties table
    result = [obj.phone,]
    # add phones from user table
    for phone in user_phones[0].split(','):
        result.append(''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), phone)))

    # return list with all phones
    return set(result)
```

And I get `all_phones` column in my filtered results:

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "user_id": 17897,
        "phone": "123456789", <--- user_properties table
        "fio": "....",
        "url": "....",
        "all_phones": [
            "123456789",
            "5512222",
            "49543"
        ] <--- user_properties.phone + user.phone
    }
]
```

}

But in the `get_queryset` I filtering only using "real" `phone` column in user_properties table. How to filter results using "virtual" `all_phones` column? Or search in two tables and get User who has one of this phone numbers? Is it's possible? Or my way is not correct?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot depend on the Django ORM to search through 2 different tables. You will either have to query twice and join the results, or normalize your data and move all phone numbers to one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about the Django ORM than Django REST framework, but rewriting the `get_queryset` method like this will search on the `phone` fields of both models:

```
from django.db.models import Q

...

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.queryset
    # phone number from GET
    phone = self.request.query_params.get('phone')

    if phone:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(phone__contains=phone)
            | Q(user__phone__contains=phone)
        )

    return queryset
```

Comment: Hi. Thank You for your answer. I gets an error: ""Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: email, phone, " ... etc (columns list from user_properties table). Will Q work with two tables without relationships? Seems like no

Comment: For the example to work, the tables will need to have a relation defined - `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField`. Can you update your post include the relevant parts of your User and UserProperties models?

Comment: Updated my post. I couldn't change my database tables - read only.

Comment: That's ok, changing the model definition should be enough. Change the `user_id` field definition and try again: `user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)` (Note that the field has been renamed from `user_id` to `user`)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This is what I need. But could You explain me: table user_properties will not be changed by Django after I run "migrate" command in future? I have managed=False and when i running migrate command I add --fake keyword.

Comment: `managed = False` already does what you need - Django won't generate migrations for these models and won't touch the underlying tables.

Comment: One more question, please give me advice: what would You do in my case, if You need to preformat column value before search? I meen that via GET request i search phone number like 123456789, but in the table column I have phone in that format: 1-234-56-7-89. ?